# Binding a list of user-defined object to a repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have the following class

```
class stu
{
    public string username;
    public string password;
    public string fname;
    public string lname;
    public string faculty;
}
```

suppose i have created this list:

```
list<stu>friends=new list<stu>();
```

i have filled this list with objects items so it now contains some students information. can any one tell me how to bind it to a repeater controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is what you are looking for :

```
class stu
{
    public string username;
    public string password;
    public string fname;
    public string lname;
    public string faculty;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<stu>friends = new List<stu>();

        foreach (var friend  in friends)
        {
            friends.Add(
                new Friends { Fname = friend.fname, LName = friend.lname, Faculty = friend.faculty }    
            );
        }
        this.rptFriends.DataSource = friendsList;
        this.rptFriends.DataBind();
}
```

.aspx Page

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFriends" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Fname</th>
                            <th>LName</th>
                            <th>Faculty</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%# Eval("Fname") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("lName") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("Faculty") %></td>
                    </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: but i need the DataSource to be the List, so the repeater fetches it object by object. i don't see that you set the List as the datasource in your code.

Comment: it didn't work, could you please check it ?
i got this:
does not contain a property with the name 'fname'

Comment: the problem is that you have make the attributes of the class as properties with {get; set;} this will work
thanks

Comment: sorry buddy, i forgot to change that part, but nice catch. cheers